# Using ICollection interface in Native C++ code

Tags: c#, c++, generics

I am trying to create an ICollection Interface pointer in Native C++ code using the below piece of code.

```
ICollectionPtr ptrPopItems (__uuidof(mscorlib::ICollection));
```

But I am getting a compliation error saying "Class not registered".
Can someone help in solving this error?

Answer (score 1):

ICollection is not a COM object, which is what you would need for something like that to work.  You need something like:

```
ICollection^ ptrPopItems = gcnew ArrayList();
```

ICollection is an interface, so you need to set it to an instance of a concrete class that implements its interace.  The `^` is a pointer to a managed object and `gcnew` calls the managed `new` to create the object.

Take a look at this C++/CLI page on Wikipedia to learn more

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI

EDIT: If you need to use C++ without the managed extensions, then you need to create classes in C# that do what you want and add the `ComVisible` attribute to the classes you want to expose.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fcfby2t.aspx

Comment: Thank you .i got it solved but i am facing another similar problem,

Comment: Hi,
I am trying to create a instance of IDictonary using the below piece of code and make use of the IDictonary->Add method.But the CoCreateInstance instance is failing with Class not registered error.When checked in the registry the CLSID is not available,Can you please let me know what is the problem and am i missing something else.
 
IDictionary *pDictionary; 
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
 if (FAILED(hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Dictionary, NULL,    
     CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_IDictionary, (void **)(&pDictionary))))

Comment: CLSID_Dictionary is {EE09B103-97E0-11CF-978F-00A02463E06F} -- check your registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{EE09B103-97E0-11CF-978F-00A02463E06F} to see if it's registered.  If not, you don't have Windows Scripting Host installed properly or perhaps don't have access to it.

Comment: Also, what are you ultimately trying to do? Do you need an IDictionary because you plan to call another COM object that requires it? In C++, you can just use std::map to get the same kind of object as a Dictionary.